# Flutter, Animations, and the Scheduler

Tags: flutter

How can I obtain the exact point in time when a new frame is rendered physically visible to the human observer? I prefer to use material widgets instead of dart:ui to put the app together.

The purpose of this effort is measurement of human reaction times which is a fundamental research method in psychological and cognitive sciences. Human reaction time is the time span between the physical onset of the stimulus on the screen/human retina and the physical onset of the human reaction, i.e. tap or click, on the device. The timestamp of the reaction is easy to obtain, so that in this question I focus on the approximation of the point in time of the stimulus presentation.

Reaction time experiments in cognitive science are similar to simple retro computer games. One approach would be to use a game framework, which is not much different from a simple Animation. In Flutter, an Animationcontroller is synced by the ticks of a Ticker which can be used to trigger setState. The synchronization to frames ensures relative low variance in time measurement, but it doesn't provide the absolute point in (system) time when the new animation frame is physically visible to the human observer. There will be a constant time lag between a call to setState and the modified widget being rendered to the screen.

So, there are two requirements:

1. Approximate the point in time when the frame is physically visible as precise as possible,
2. guarantee the change in the widget tree really being rendered in the timestamped frame instead of being rendered in a later frame, due to a preparation that takes to long.

Is there an approach to satisfy both requirements?

Comment: see `<flooter_root>/examples/layers/README.md`

Comment: @pskink   The hint to  these examples doesn't answer the question.  "onBeginFrame" and "onDrawFrame" are called some time before the the cange in a wiget is actually rendered. I need the exact point in time when the change in a widget is rendered to the display.

Comment: so to minimize the delay you most likely need "raw" (the most raw layer with direct `Canvas` drawing) or "rendering" (using `RenderObject` classes) layers (and not "widget" one) - check `<flooter_root>/examples/layers/raw` or `<flooter_root>/examples/layers/rendering`

Comment: and when using "raw" approach you could try [onReportTimings](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Window/onReportTimings.html)

Comment: @pskink That's a very good hint ... probabely the best solution.

Comment: its just a "wild guess" as i never tried it by myself: i just found it two hours ago and thought it could be helpful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what how precise you really need to be. Given the complexities of modern, multitasking operating systems, I don't think you will be able to find out *exactly* when the new frame becomes visible - there's just too many variables to factor in, both in software and the display hardware itself.

That may not matter, depending on the nature of your experiment.

The first thing you should do is *validate* your test apparatus. By that, I mean you may need to figure out a way of measuring the difference in time between when Flutter says the frame has finished, and when the frame is physically there on screen. If that duration is consistent enough, then you can apply a correction to your data.

I think the best way to get frame times in Flutter are the callbacks in [SchedulerBinding](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding-mixin.html). I would have a look at the difference in time you get when using `addPersistentFrameCallback` compared to `addPostFrameCallback`. From the documentation, it looks like `addPostFrameCallback` will be the best fit:

> This callback is run during a frame, just after the persistent frame callbacks (which is when the main rendering pipeline has been flushed)

Another thing you will need to validate is the input latency (time between physically tapping the screen vs tap registered in the app).

Again, all of this absolute precision may not matter, depending on the kind of experiment. Human visual reaction time is [approximately 250ms](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4456887/). If you are running your app on a 120Hz display, then a single frame is 8ms - so you can measure to +/- 3%, which is pretty good. If your experiment is about comparing responses to different visual cues, for example, then the absolute precision isn't as important as the relative performance of each cue.